# Having a Issue with program not working correctly in python

Tags: python, loops, error-handling

```
       empmangpro = True
       employees = []
       while empmangpro == True:
             try:
                 empcount = len(employees)
                 print("--------------------Employee Management System--------------------")
                 print("")
                 print("There are "+str(empcount)+" employees in the system.")
                 print("")
                 print("------------------------------------------------------------------")

                 print("1. Add new employee")
                 print("2. View all employees")
                 programselection = int(input("Please select your option number: "))

                 if programselection == 1:
                 employee = []
                 employee.append(input("First and Last Name: "))
                 employee.append(input("Social Security Number: "))
                 employee.append(input("Phone Number: "))
                 employee.append(input("Email Address: "))
                 employee.append(input("Salary:$"))
                 employees.append(employee)
                 elif programselection == 2:
                      i = 0
                      j = 0
                      empstr = ""
                      while i < int(empcount):
                          while j < 5:
                             empstr = empstr + employees[i][j]
                      if j != 4:
                         empstr = empstr + ", "
                         j += 1
                         if i+1 != int(empcount):
                            empstr = empstr + "\n"
                            j = 0
                            i += 1
                           print(empstr)
                           print[employees]
                        elif programselection < 3:
                           empmangpro = False
                        else:
                             print("Please enter valid information")
                except ValueError:
                print("Please enter valid information")
                continue
```

I have option 1 working where you can add multiple employees to the system, but when I select option 2, nothing happens.  It is supposed to print all the employees that I add. What did I do wrong here? I only have been programming for less than a month, so I have still have lots to learn.  What am I missing or did wrong?

Comment: After your `if programselection == 1:` do you indent next line onwards?  Right now appears not.  Also the `elif` should be at same level as `if`.

Comment: I messed up the spacing while posting this  I don't get a error or anything  its just when I selection option 2   nothing happens  its just blank

Comment: You're asking us to debug your incorrectly-spaced code in a language like python where it can alter program control.  How do we know where it was copy-pasta or it is the actual issue (hiding).

Comment: Hey @Corey sorry if I came across as rude.  I want to help you and ask that you put in the effort to properly format your code block.

Comment: its okay I think i got the spacing correctly now?

Answer (score 1):

Is not very clear what you are trying to do at option 2. Try commenting your code in the future. The tabbing in your post was not accurate so I made some guesses. Maybe this will help you with your problem:

```
empmangpro = True
employees = []
while empmangpro == True:
    try:
        empcount = len(employees)
        print("--------------------Employee Management System--------------------")
        print("")
        print("There are "+str(empcount)+" employees in the system.")
        print("")
        print("------------------------------------------------------------------")

        print("1. Add new employee")
        print("2. View all employees")
        programselection = int(input("Please select your option number: "))

        if programselection == 1:
            employee = []
            employee.append(input("First and Last Name: "))
            employee.append(input("Soci1al Security Number: "))
            employee.append(input("Phone Number: "))
            employee.append(input("Email Address: "))
            employee.append(input("Salary:$"))
            employees.append(employee)
        elif programselection == 2:
            i = 0
            j = 0
            empstr = ""
            while i < empcount:
                print(str(employees[i])+"\n")
                i += 1

        elif programselection > 2:
            empmangpro = False
            print("Stopping programm")
        else:
            print("Please enter valid information")
    except ValueError:
        print("Please enter valid information")
        continue
```

Also if you want to stop the program use `elif programselection > 2:` instead of `elif programselection < 3:`.

Answer (score 0):

You said option 1 works.  OK (I see some indentation issues).

For option 2, I'll be honest I did not quite follow your code.  If you want option 2 to print all employees, I suggest to create an `Employee` class.  That way, you can `print(employee)` anywhere.

Can put this into `employee.py`:

```
class Employee:
    def __init__(self, name): # can add all you need social security, ...
        first, last = name.split(' ')
        self.first = first # add a new line per new parameter
        self.last = last
    def __str__(self):
        # here you can add all of your logic
        # to properly format social security, phone number, etc.
        # just be sure to return a string, and not print a string!
        return f'{self.last}, {self.first}'
```

Then in your main file:

```
import employee # put at top of file
employees = [Employee('John Doe'), Employee('Jane Doe')] # sample data
for e in employees:
    print(e)
```

Output:

```
Doe, John
Doe, Jane
```

As for incorrectly spaced:

```
             if programselection == 1:
                 employee = []
                 # ...
                 employees.append(employee)
             elif programselection == 2:
```

And:

```
            except ValueError:
                print("Please enter valid information")
                continue
```